# How to create a default attribute for text and chain additional attributes as needed in RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm still new to javascript and even newer to Raphael-JS. I need to streamline my code and remove any redundancy (see below). Many of my variables are essentially the same, with the exception of one or two attributes.

```
var textLine1 = paper3.text(19, 40, "TODAY'S RATES.").attr({
    'text-anchor':'start',
    'font-family' : 'Arial, sans-serif',
    fill: "#ffffff"
});
var textLine3 = paper3.text(19, 210, "RATE JUMBO").attr({
    'text-anchor':'start',
    'font-family' : 'Arial, sans-serif',
    fill: "#ffffff",
    "font-size": 13
});
```

Is there a way I can set a default value for all text attributes, and chain specific ones to the existing? If not what is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use an object for some, or clone as a couple of ideas. Maybe it will depend on what varies as to how you want to approach it. Here's an example jsbin though http://jsbin.com/ujavErA/1/edit?html,js,output (fiddle wasn't working).

```
var textLine1 = paper.text(19, 40, "TODAY'S RATES.").attr({
    'text-anchor':'start',
    'font-family' : 'Arial, sans-serif',
    fill: "#444444"
});

var textLine3 = paper.text(19, 60, "RATE JUMBO").attr({
    'text-anchor':'start',
    'font-family' : 'Arial, sans-serif',
    fill: "#444444",
    "font-size": 13
}); 

var textLine4 = textLine1.clone().attr({ x: 19, y : 80, text : 'Some clone stuff' });

var defaults = {

  'text-anchor':'start',
  'font-family' : 'Arial, sans-serif',
  'fill': "#444444",
  "font-size": 13
};


var textLine5 = paper.text(19,100,'Some more stuff with an object as default').attr(   defaults );

var textLine6 = paper.text(19,120, 'Some more stuff').attr( defaults ).attr("font-size", 16);
```

Comment: Ian thanks for your feedback. I didn't think about using a clone method!